# Executing scripts with parameters & additional paths in Python and catching exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm supposed to be checking HW for a large course, and one of the things I'd like to do is to make sure the students actually submitted runnable code.

I wrote a script, and after much work, I still haven't gotten it to work the same way I want it to:

I usually work with the Spyder IDE. there, you can just open a script, click `Run` and the script is run. Relative imports work. However, in spite of all of my attempts, my code still gets exceptions when trying to run a script which would otherwise work.

```
# imports:
import os
from os.path import join
from runpy import run_path
import sys

root = "path/to/folder"
dir = ["list", "of", "directories", "in", "root", "folder"]
prev_path = sys.path[:]
for _dir in dirs:
            sys.path.append(join(root,_dir))
sys.path.append(root)
sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]] + params[1].split(" ")
    try:
        run_path(join(root,FileNames[1]),{'sys.argv':sys.argv},run_name="__main__")
    except Exception as e:
                    #make a note of it
sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]]
```

Sometimes this works, but it almost always gives me some exception or another which seems to be a result of import failures for things that are in one of the subfolders of the folder in which the code being executed is.

Also, changing `sys.path` and `sys.argv` doesn't seem like the right way to go, but nothing else I've tried worked, so... Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Two problems (at least) with the code: `dirs`, `params`, and `Filenames` are not defined. The key ``'sys.argv'`` sets the invalid name `sys.argv` in the main module and _not_ the `argv` attribute of the `sys` module. I guess all you need to do is to set the parameters in `sys.argv` and change the working directory to the one the script lives in.  The modules and packages relative to the script should be found.

Comment: If this doesn't work, please post a small _runnable_ example setup which demonstrates your problem in a way others can reproduce it.